# How to implement localization from fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, locale, arabic-support

I am switching application language English to Arabic and vice versa from a fragment.
The code below works, it loads the values-ar\strings.xml and the language is changed from english to arabic. The app's UI elements doesn't change immediately based on the updated language settings, **RTL alignment**. The change is only reflected when application is closed and reopened.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getActivity().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
getActivity().recreate()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked, add this to the activity holding the fragment and call it instead of `getActivity().recreate()`.

```
public void restartActivity() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in the manifest file.

```
android:configChanges="locale|orientation"
```

Comment: `android:configChanges` was already added to manifest.